# Одна кнопка на два ListView — как сделать, чтобы кнопка действовала на активном списке?

Tags: wpf, listview, xaml, mvvm, button

По шаблону MVVM в WPF есть 2 ListView для реализации схемы Master/Detail. Также есть панель с кнопками, управляющими добавлением, удалением и т.д. элементов в эти списки.

Вопрос: как можно узнавать о том, в каком из ListView пользователь был, когда нажал кнопку на панели кнопок? Хотелось бы иметь по одной кнопке на каждую операцию редактирования элементов в этих списках. Т.е. что бы кнопка "знала" для какого ListView ее нажали.

Comment: Если вам подошло какое-то решение, пожалуйста, отметьте его как правильное.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Можно сделать таким образом:

1. Заведите во вью-модели свойство, определяющее текущий активный контрол. Это должна быть не ссылка на контрол из вью, а, например, перечисление или целочисленный индекс.
2. Реагируйте на событие `GotFocus` в списках установкой соответствующего значения этого свойства.
3. В обработчиках событий нажатия на кнопки сверяйтесь со значением этого свойства.

Ниже простой пример, использующий `System.Windows.Interactivity.*` из Blend (NuGet: [Exression.Blend.Sdk](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Expression.Blend.Sdk/)) и `GalaSoft.MvvmLight.CommandWpf.RelayCommand` из MVVM Light (NuGet: [MvvmLight](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MvvmLight/)). Если вы пользуетесь более мощной библиотекой, например, Caliburn.Micro (NuGet: [Caliburn.Micro](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Caliburn.Micro/)), то писанины будет заметно меньше.

**MainWindow.xaml.cs**

```
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Input;
using GalaSoft.MvvmLight.CommandWpf;

namespace Sor416977WpfActiveList
{
    public enum MasterDetail
    {
        Master,
        Detail,
    }

    public class ShellModel
    {
        public ObservableCollection<string> ItemsMaster { get; private set; }
        public ObservableCollection<string> ItemsDetail { get; private set; }
        public MasterDetail CurrentList { get; private set; }

        public ICommand SetCurrentListCommand { get; private set; }
        public ICommand FooCommand { get; private set; }

        public ShellModel ()
        {
            ItemsMaster = new ObservableCollection<string> { "M1", "M2" };
            ItemsDetail = new ObservableCollection<string> { "D1", "D2" };
            SetCurrentListCommand = new RelayCommand<MasterDetail>(SetCurrentListExecute);
            FooCommand = new RelayCommand(FooExecute);
        }

        private void SetCurrentListExecute (MasterDetail currentList)
        {
            CurrentList = currentList;
        }

        private void FooExecute ()
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Executing Foo on " + CurrentList);
        }
    }

    public partial class MainWindow
    {
        public MainWindow ()
        {
            DataContext = new ShellModel();
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}
```

**MainWindow.xaml**

```
<Window x:Class="Sor416977WpfActiveList.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" mc:Ignorable="d"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Sor416977WpfActiveList"
        Width="400" Height="200"
        d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance local:ShellModel}">
    <DockPanel LastChildFill="True">
        <Button Content="Foo" Command="{Binding FooCommand}" DockPanel.Dock="Bottom"/>
        <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding ItemsMaster}" DockPanel.Dock="Left" Width="200">
            <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                <i:EventTrigger EventName="GotFocus">
                    <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding SetCurrentListCommand}"
                            CommandParameter="{x:Static local:MasterDetail.Master}"/>
                </i:EventTrigger>
            </i:Interaction.Triggers>
        </ListBox>
        <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding ItemsDetail}">
            <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                <i:EventTrigger EventName="GotFocus">
                    <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding SetCurrentListCommand}"
                            CommandParameter="{x:Static local:MasterDetail.Detail}"/>
                </i:EventTrigger>
            </i:Interaction.Triggers>
        </ListBox>
    </DockPanel>
</Window>
```

Answer (score 2):

Я бы реализовал это как `CompositeCommand` (например, [из Prism](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.practices.prism.commands.compositecommand%28v=pandp.50%29.aspx), или легко самому написать).

При таком подходе каждая из VM, соответствующих спискам, выставляет наружу `ICommand`, соответствующую добавлению элемента. `CompositeCommand` ссылается на эти команды, переключаясь между ними через [`ShouldExecute`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.practices.prism.commands.compositecommand.shouldexecute%28v=pandp.50%29.aspx) (VM знает, какой из списков активен!).

Теперь кнопку можно забиндить на эту самую `CompositeCommand`.

---

Пример:

```
addCommand = new CompositeCommand(c =>
    {
        var activeList = DocumentVM.ActiveListVM;
        return activeList != null && c == activeList.AddCommand;
    });
```

и при создании нового `ActiveListVM` нужно зарегистртировать его:

```
addCommand.RegisterCommand(list.SaveCommand);
```

Здесь создаётся команда, которая перенаправляет запросы к команде `AddCommand` активного списка.

Если вы не используете Prism, вот вам код `CompositeCommand`: http://pastebin.com/kbCuA1Cz

Comment: Вас, не затруднит, маленький пример с предложенным решением с помощью CompositeCommand?

Comment: @DmitryB2014: Обновил ответ.